# User matching query does not exist using authentication

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-authentication

I've created a user with my following code:

**views.py** (register view works fine but login view doesn't)

```
def register(request):  
    if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserProfileForm(request.POST) 

    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()

        username = ... 
        u = User.objects.create_user(username, user.email, user.password)
        u.save()
        ... 

    else:
        return HttpResponse('Nombre o contrasena incorrectos.')
else:
    form = UserProfileForm()

...


def log_in(request):   
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserLoginForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        try:
            u = User.objects.get(email=email, password=password)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return HttpResponse('Email o contrasena incorrectos.')
        ...
else:
    form = UserLoginForm()
...
```

The register view creates my custom user without any problem, but when I want to use it to login into my app, the login view throws a `User.DoesNotExist` exception. Why is that?

Comment: Have you checked in debugger or with prints what do you get in ```email``` and ```password``` variables?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here:

```
u = User.objects.get(email=email, password=password)
```

It has no sense, you can't compare `password` field value, because it is not stored raw in database.

To check is user has provided correct password, you shoud use `authenticate` built-in function:

```
u = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
```

You can see solid example here:
http://code.runnable.com/UpBfbcg4PNU0AAHG/how-to-check-if-the-user-is-authenticated-in-django-for-python-authentication-and-httprequest

..or in official Django documentation (`login` function example):
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login

Comment: Hello Igor, I changed the code as you said and added a HttpResponse for making a breaking point, the problem is partially solved, it doesn't throws the DoesNotExist exception anymore, but my app doesn't recognise yet my created user with the email and password introduced in the login form, can yourself or anybody else help me again? Thank you anyway :)

Comment: You should do it in 2 steps: first find the user by email, then use username of the user to call ```authenticate``` function with the user you found at previous step and the password user has provided in form.